# C++ incrementals builds for continuous integration

Tags: c++, visual-c++, build-automation, incremental-build

We have a fairly large C++ project built in VS2005 that can take up to 40 minutes to compile and build from scratch, and a further 10 minutes for the installers as the software is being built in both  32-bit and 64-bit configurations. I would like to reduce this time to somewhere around 10 minutes at least as I feel it's important to get fast build feedback when using continuous integration.

When using incremental builds by deleting the final linked files but not the .obj files the build process seems to go much faster, however errors seem to pop up here and there, such as .dlls not being able to be loaded. From a clean build everything works fine. I am using TeamCity as the CI system of choice.

Maybe the incremental build behavior is better in later versions of Visual Studio and it might be a good motivation to upgrade ? Has anyone encountered similar issues?

Comment: Could yo elaborate on the errors that you mention? I'm having a hard time seeing why a partial build would provoke DLLs loading problems. Does this mean that you *always* make a clean build of your project for it to work?

Comment: We have a small script that calls LoadLibrary() on all the .dlls, just to make sure all the dependency requirements are met. It seems to fail for some of the .dlls. The problem doens't seem to occur if we build through visual studio or when using msbuild from command line and calling it twice. But I think the incremental builds depend on source code dates, it could be that when TeamCity updates the code from the repository the date modified on the file will get reverted as well (we are using mercurial). I will investigate that further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question.

When I was putting together a CI system for a large C++ project for Microsoft Visual Studio 2003/2005/2008 I enounteded problems as well with incremental builds. Especially when using pre-compiled headers it seems to not work under all circumstances to do an incremental build. I would be interested hear if someone has a detailed explanation of this, i.e. what works and what doesn't.

In my case, the project took more than one hour to build from scratch, so in order to have some reasonable speed of feedback intraday, I ended up doing a clean nightly build which was the release build and intraday I used incremental builds based on the nightly. This worked fairly well, except for cases when the incremental building wasn't able to pick up changes correctly and re-compile all necessary things. I tried this approach because I consider getting feedback fast very important and if the incremental build fails once a month or less, I was ready to live with the comprimise.

In general, I like to have things better than what I described above, so in other projects where it has been possible to get more hardware and re-organize the components to be built in parallel, I usually do complete re-builds. If you can do builds in parallel you can speed up building a lot.

Other things to consider are:

- include vs. forward declaration
- template usage
- general dependencies between things
- take out parts of projects as independent libraries, which can even be pre-built.

There are a lot of things which can be done to get building faster and I would in most cases consider these to incremental builds.

Answer (score 2):

I can't actually answer your question, but since you're looking for speeding up your builds, this blog post about fast builds with Visual Studio 2010 and an SSD might be helpful. http://qualapps.blogspot.com/2010/09/lightning-fast-builds-with-visual.html

Comment: thanks for the link. I have been thinking about SSDs, as well as upgrading the CPU as well. Obviously you can always throw more hardware at the problem, I was hoping to find a way to make the incremental builds work in a reliable way and if that works it will be even faster with new hardware.

Comment: Now, I don't want to get you confused :), but there are also contrary opinions about SSD, as this one from Jeff Palermo. http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/speeding-up-the-build-ndash-ditch-the-ssd-and-go-for-the-ram-drive/

Answer (score 1):

My experience is that often, especially for debug builds, the bottleneck is disk IO. It helps to compress the output and intermediate files directories. Also, I have seen some builds being faster when not using incremental linking feature (Enable Incremental Linking - No). Another setting to consider is to turn off browse information generation (Enable Browse Information - None). Also, do not forget to use the parallel compilation feature of VS 2005. Since often it is the IO that is the bottleneck, it helps to use more build threads than there are CPUs.

Comment: Yes we are using the "undocumented" parallel build flag, and it has helped a bit. I will try to set up a ramdisk or something similar and see if that will help the process.

Comment: @Can Gencer: What undocumeted parallel build flag? I meant the "Tools - Options - Projects and Solutions - Build and Run - maximum number of parallel project builds" setting. If you are using MSBuild or VCBuild, both have some options with the same effect.

Comment: You mean building projects in parallel. I haven't tried that, as I remembering reading long time ago that it's not very reliable. I will give it a try. I meant the /MP flag for multi-core compilation. It is available in VS2008 and in VS2005 as an undocumented flag. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385193.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Never noticed the behavior myself, but I would first suspect Link Time Code Generation. For continuous integration, you could skip that.

I should also mention IncrediBuild. Throwing hardware at the problem, especially hardware that you already have, is a quick win.

Comment: All the projects have it setup as "Default", which I assume it means not enabled. Incredibuild sounds interesting, will investigate that.